# TypeError: t.slice is not a function (caused by "undefined") ng-table

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm facing with this issue in one page which contains table that uses ng-table.

```
Here is console log:
TypeError: t.slice is not a function (caused by "undefined") at o
(https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js:1:14033) at s 
(https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js:1:14326) at e 
(https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js:1:16847) at l.reload (https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js:1:21598) at
https://unpkg.com/ng-table@2.0.2/bundles/ng-table.min.js:1:6817 at 
Scope.$digest (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:17286:23) at
Scope.$apply (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:17552:24) at 
done (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11697:47) at 
completeRequest (http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11903:7) at
XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded     
(http://localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js:11836:9) undefined
```

Do you have a clue about what causes this error?

**EDIT :**
I added my codes to plunker.

https://plnkr.co/edit/LpuWWu8vB5Ng5EZegd8t?p=preview

Comment: Your error is `t.slice is not a function`. Means, that function `slice()` doesnt exists on object `t`. Could you create a plnkr or fiddle to reproduce that error? Note that `slice()` is only available on `array` vars. So I guess, `t` is not an array.

Comment: But it says that error occurs in ng-table.min.js:1. There is no t or .slice() in my controller. @lin

Comment: Please create a plnkr/fiddle to make it reproduceable. Or add your controller code.

Comment: @lin added my codes to plnkr but couldn't run.

Comment: Well made, its hard to help you so. Please fix your plnkr to make your problem reproduceable.

Comment: Okay I found my mistake. I was trying to create a table with null dataset. When I initialize tableParams, I gave empty dataset and it's done. Thanks for your effort. @lin